# Rate of Change of Hull Moving Average Indicator for TradingView

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm new to Pine Editor. Can anyone help me write a code for Rate of Change of Hull Moving Average Indicator for TradingView ? Its a very useful indicator. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine built-in hull moving average and `roc` function as in the example below

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © e2e4mfck

//@version=4
study("Rate of Hull Change", overlay = false)

// Inputs
i_hullLength    = input(9, "Hull Length", minval=1)
i_rocLength     = input(1, "Rate of Change Length", minval=1)
i_src           = input(close, title="Source")

hullma  = wma(2*wma(i_src, i_hullLength/2)-wma(i_src, i_hullLength), round(sqrt(i_hullLength)))
rocHull = roc(hullma, i_rocLength)

plot(rocHull)
```